# Apache POI in Java causes trouble (XSSFWorkbook)

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I am actually trying to read an XLS file with Apache POI, but my code somehow doesn't work. IntelliJ tells me that, on line 28, creating the XSSFWorkbook causes the trouble. Would you have a brief look and maybe answer if you are in this?

```
package Parse;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class poi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\jd\\Desktop\\test\\VW_XML\\in_xls.xlsx"));

            //Create workbook instance
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            //read sheet
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            //iterate rows
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                // for each row all columns
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    //check cell type
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "t");
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "t");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");

            }
            file.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception stacktrace ?

Comment: How does IntelliJ show you where's the issue? Or is it in fact the stacktrace that you read? If positive, maybe you could share it with us.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException

Comment: add xmlbeans jar to build path

Comment: ok, i will try and give you the result a little later.

Comment: I used to use POI until I discovered "Apache Metamodel".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place all the following jars in BuildPath and run!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How do you add POI to your project? Do you use Maven or something like that? You might be missing some dependencies.

Cut out from my dependency:tree :

```
org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.10-FINAL:compile
 +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.10-FINAL:compile
 |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.5:compile
 \- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.10-FINAL:compile
    \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:compile
        \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
```

Do you have all that jars in your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

[How to read excel(.xlsx) in java using poi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357812/how-to-read-excel-xlsx-in-java-using-poi)

this link and your comments helped me a lot.

i needed to add more jar files to my project.

poi-3.9.jar
poi-ooxml-3.9.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7.jar
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar

ty a lot for replys and have a nice day.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add these jar files ::

CLASSPATH:

“C:\poi-3.9\poi-3.9-20121203.jar;”

“C:\poi-3.9\poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar;”

“C:\poi-3.9\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar;”

“C:\poi-3.9\ooxml-lib\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;”

“C:\poi-3.9\ooxml-lib\xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar;”

Click the below link for the above jar files::
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java_Free_Code/Database/Download_wca_workbook_assistant_Free_Java_Code.htm

Best of Luck..

Comment: Those are very old versions (the clue is in the date in the filename!). Why are you suggesting using such old versions instead of the latest ones?